# Excluding generated-sources from source:jar

Tags: maven, maven-3

Using the `source:jar` goal, how do I configure it such that the `target/generated-sources` folder is excluded from the archive? I've tried a number of different configurations, and can't get any of them to work.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <excludes>
      <exclude>target/generated-sources</exclude>
    </excludes>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I've tried various things in the `exlude` tag such as `target/generated-sources/**/*.java`, `com/mycompany/**/*.java` and because I became so convinced it wasn't even looking at that, just tried `*.java` and it seems nothing gets excluded.

This is Maven 3.0.5 and the source plugin 2.2.1. I'm running this from the Maven CLI. Below is the complete POM for those interested.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>foo-service</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.8</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>wsimport</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <packageName>com.example</packageName>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>target/generated-sources</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Can you show the full pom file? Which maven version do you use? Are you using Maven from command line of from Eclipse/IDE ?

Comment: @khmarbaise I've updated the question as you asked. This is Maven 3.0.5 CLI.

Answer (score 0):

hopefully you figured this out - but for what it's worth.  This configuration works to exclude anything in the com.foo.server package and does not include the target folders.  Since this runs relative to the src/com directory, your problem may be that your project is configured to put the generated sources in the wrong directory. /target should be next to your /src folder which wouldn't be included in the source plugin, since it would start at /src/main/java/

```
 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>com/foo/server/**</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>

                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>

                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```